# Mongo $aggregate and $filter not working as expected

Tags: mongodb

I have documents with an array in them. I am searching for the China tasks in the data array.
As you can see 2 documents are retrieved with many elements in the ‘data’ array with the criteria I applied.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijra1.png)

this is one of the data array elements, which I am looking for:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gFfs.png)

I wrote this code: It runs but returns 0 in the data array although I know they are available.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy1ay.png)

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB("quantum-ingress");
db.getCollection("ingressPayload").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            $match : { 
                'schemaVersion' : 'task', 
                'data.TASKLIST' : /.*China.*/i, 
                'timestamp' : { '$gt' : ISODate("2021-08-01T00:00:19.000+0000") }
            }
        }, 
        {
$project:{ 
    data:{
        $filter:{
            input:'$data',
            as: 'data',
            cond: {$eq:  ['$data.TASKLIST' , /.*China.*/i  ]}
        }
    }
}
}
    ]);
```

I couldn't figure out why I cant bring the elements that I know they are in the data array? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the version of MongoDB you're using ?

Comment: And can you show the content of one data expended. (One value containing "China").

Answer (score 1):

This equality test will match if the `TASKLIST` field is the regular expression `/.*China.*/i`:

```
{$eq:  ['$data.TASKLIST' , /.*China.*/i  ]}
```

But that will never happen because `$data` is an array.

You probably meant to use `$$data` to refer to the element being processed, and use `$regexMatch`:

```
{$regexMatch: { input: "$$data.TASKLIST", regex: "China", options: "i" }}
```

It would probably be less ambiguous to avoid reusing the same variable name:

```
$filter:{
            input:'$data',
            as: 'element',
            cond: {$regexMatch: { 
                    input: "$$element.TASKLIST", 
                    regex: "China", 
                    options: "i" 
            }}
        }
```